# How come positioned parameters pass through the null safety check in Dart?

Tags: function, dart, dart-null-safety

The following lines of code aren't valid in Dart:

```dart
void introduce({String name, int age}) {
  print('My name is $name and I am $age years old.');
}
```

The compiler will complain about the null safety of the parameters.

But if we switch to the positioned parameters, the compiler suddenly stops complaining about the null safety of the parameters, and the following becomes valid:

```dart
void introduce(String name, int age) {
  print('My name is $name and I am $age years old.');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Positioned parameters are inherently required. Named and positional *optional* parameters are optionally passed by the caller and it's therefore possible that they're `null`. One can make the normally optional named parameters required by marking them `required`.

```dart
void introduce({required String name, required int age}) {
  print('My name is $name and I am $age years old.');
}
```